# Apply canvas composite to only two operations

Tags: javascript, canvas, composite

I need to draw a pizza with opacity so that it looks "empty", and progressively fill the pizza with the full colored image in a clockwise manner using canvas.

I started out by drawing the "empty" pizza, using the same image with a `globalAlpha` inferior to 1.

Then I drew the "full" pizza right above it.

Finally, I progressively draw an arc as the mask for the pizza and applied a composite operation on it, `"destination-atop"`. This effectively masks the pizza like I want it to, but with the adverse consequence of also masking the first pizza, the "empty" one. I only want it to hide the second pizza I'm drawing.

So basically, I need to do a composite between only two operations, and not between *everything drawn previously* and *everything drawn after*. Here is my code:

```
var ratio = 0;
var image = new Image();
image.src = "http://www.pizza.la-recette.net/img/pizza-001.jpg";
image.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    setInterval(function() {
        ratio += 0.01;
        ratio = ratio % 1;

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        //Draw "empty" pizza image
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.6;
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        //Draw actual pizza image
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        //Draw mask
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(image.width / 2, image.height / 2);
        ctx.arc(image.width / 2, image.height / 2, image.width / 2, -Math.PI / 2, (-Math.PI / 2) + ((Math.PI * 2) * ratio), false);
        ctx.fill();
    }, 100);
};​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JwqBb/1/)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of drawing a mask, you can create a clipping region before you draw the actual pizza image. The code is almost the same, you basically replace the call to `ctx.fill()` with `ctx.clip()` and move the second `drawImage` down. You also need to `save`/`restore` the context state to reset the clipping region each time.

```
var ratio = 0;
var image = new Image();
image.src = "http://www.pizza.la-recette.net/img/pizza-001.jpg";
image.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    setInterval(function() {
        ratio += 0.01;
        ratio = ratio % 1;

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        //Draw "empty" pizza image
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.6;
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        ctx.save();

        //Set the clipping region
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(image.width / 2, image.height / 2);
        ctx.arc(image.width / 2, image.height / 2, image.width / 2, -Math.PI / 2, (-Math.PI / 2) + ((Math.PI * 2) * ratio), false);
        ctx.clip();

        //Draw actual pizza image
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);     

        ctx.restore();
    }, 100);
};
```

Comment: Ah-ha! So everything drawn after that will only be shown if it is inside this clipping region then?